# Is it advisable to use extern to avoid header dependency?

Tags: c++, coding-style, include, extern

I have eliminated two header inclusions in a translation unit using extern.  Is this advisable?

My specific situation: I have a class called `ParseTree` that accumulates `Token*`'s.  `ParseTree*` is a private member of `Parser`.

Initially, I had the following lines in `parse_tree.cc`.

```
#include "parser.h"
#include "token.h"
```

After analyzing my code, I isolated the two functions that actually had external dependencies and replaced the includes with the following:

```
extern std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Token& t); // @token.h
extern bool hasPriority(const Token* p_tok1, Token* p_tok2); // @parser.h
```

Both solutions appear to work.  Are there any hidden dangers of which I should be aware when selecting extern over include?

Comment: External linkage is the default for function declarations so `extern` itself is redundant.

Comment: That's a very good point I overlooked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use `extern` declarations, you're unnecessarily repeating yourself by restating the prototype of the function everywhere you use it. With a header file, if you want to change the prototype, you only need to change it in one place.

So no, don't use `extern` when you already have a suitable header file.

Comment: People seem to strongly advise reducing dependencies and keeping relationships between translation units to a minimum.  For instance, pimpl and forward declaration.  How is this technique different from those two?  Pimpl idiom in particular has an abundance of potential downsides/complications..

Comment: +1 for "suitable header file".  I've seen use for the other option as a build-time optimization when many large header files got chained in by a single include.

Comment: @Jordan: You don't have to change pimpls when you update the true (one) definition.  What you described *is* forward declaration, and ideally it would be contained in a "suitable" (not dependency-inflating) header file.

Comment: @Jordan: With Pimpl, you are not going to change the type of the pimpl pointer. With forward declaration, you're not likely to change the name of the type. But with functions, you can easily change the definition of the parameters to that function. It's simply a matter of the frequency of change. Also, people generally suggest putting forward declarations in a _header_, one that is separate from the definition of those types. That way, if you need the declarations, you can include a small header.

Comment: @Merlyn: So take home message, unless I can justify a build-time optimization, its not worth trying to outsmart the compiler?

Comment: @Jordan: Don't let someone else think for you (unless they are a mainstream compiler developer).  There will be a cost, and your benefit may exceed it (especially if you get creative with your mitigations - code gen, submitting patches to the library maintainers, etc).  But taking blind cost will be very costly indeed :)

Comment: @Jordan, if you think it is worthwhile, you may create new header(s) which would be included in parse_tree.cc, parser.h and token.h; but there are two rules I strongly recommend not to break: an header should be self-contained (ideally enforce by having a CU which has it has first header) and, excepted for classes, there should be at most one declaration which isn't the definition, CU which need it should include the file which contain it. Minimizing the number of includes is worthwhile, but subordinated to these rules.

Comment: @AProgrammer: To generalize creating a header for the operator<< overloads, I would create an operator_print.h that would hold all of the overloaded << function prototypes for Node, Token, and ParseTree.  Would I include operator_print.h in only token.cc, node.cc, and parse_tree.cc, or would I also put them in token.h, node.h, and ParseTree.h?

Answer (score 1):

> Both solutions appear to work. Are there any hidden dangers of which I should be aware when selecting extern over include?

Yes. The API may be changing, and the compiler won't work for you, it will work against you.

Learn to use the compiler to your advantage. No, not only "NOW", on the long term I mean. The long term is where you make stupid mistakes, not when there's everything fresh in your head. Yes, your brain's memory is somehow volatile.

Answer (score 1):

Usually one reduces dependencies by forward-declaring classes. Here's an example. Say we have two prerequisite headers, parser.h and token.h, defined as follows:

parser.h:

```
class Parser
{
public:
  void doFoo();
  void doBar();
  // ... lots of other stuff
};
```

token.h:

```
class Token
{
public:
  void doQuux();
  void doBaz();
  // ... continues for a while
};
```

Now, having a "user,h" which uses those two, instead of writing it like:

```
#include "parser.h"
#include "token.h"

void useParserAndToken( Parser &, Token & );
```

you write

```
class Parser;
class Token;

void useParserAndToken( Parser &, Token & );
```

This way you end up saying that there are classes Parser and Token, but how they are defined exactly doesn't matter. This results in faster compiles.

In order to reduce dependencies you usually only forward-declare classes. Duplicating function declarations doesn't make much sense, on the other hand.